# Overriding button functionality in kivy using an another button

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

Currently I am making a very simple interface which asks user to input parameters for a test and then run the test. The test is running brushless dc motor for several minutes. So when the run button is pressed the button is engaged for the time period till the function is finished executing. I have another stop button which should kill the test but currently cant use it since the run button is kept pressed till the function is finished executing and stop button cant be used during the test. I want to stop the test with pressing the stop button even if the run button function is currently being executed. The run button should release and the function should continuously check the stop function for stopping the test. Let me know how this can be executed.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try adding more relevant details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that all your code it taking place sequentially in a single thread. Once your first button is pressed, all of the results of that pressing are followed through before anything else can happen.

You can avoid this by running the motor stuff in a separate thread. Your stop button will then need to interrupt that thread.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of interrupting the thread I set a parameter when a stop function in second thread is called and the first thread keeps checking for the parameter value and stops when the parameter changes.